# Spring-Integration-DSL & Soap Service Soap header is not getting invoked

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to call a soap service with spring integration DSL, have some custom header that needs to be added.

Constructed marshellingoutboundgateway. Trying to override DefaultSoapHeaderMapper but none of the overridden methods are getting called.

Trying to construct some thing like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ObjectType34 >

        </ObjectType34>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <ObjectType12 >

        </ObjectType12>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is a sample in : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/ws.adoc

looks like only available in 5.0

posted detail code.

Any insights will be helpful.

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Info Info = ctx.getBean(Info.class);

        //Constructing request Payload
        ObjectType12 getInfoType = new ObjectFactory().ObjectType12();
        JAXBElement<GetInfoType> getInfoTypeJAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createGetInfo(getInfoType);
        JAXBElement<GetInfoResponseType> getInfoResponseType = Info.getInfo(getInfoTypeJAXBElement);
        System.out.println(getInfoResponseType.getName());
        ctx.close();
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface Info {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "convert.input")
        JAXBElement<GetInfoResponseType> getInfo(JAXBElement<GetInfoType> InfoType);

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow convert() {

        StringResult result = new StringResult();

        return flow -> flow
                .wireTap(f -> f.<JAXBElement, String>transform(ele -> {
                    jaxb2Marshaller().marshal(ele, result);
                    return result.toString();
                }).log())
                .handle(endpoint());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("org.abc", "com.abc");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway endpoint() {
        MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway("https://example.com/v1", jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());

        gateway.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultSoapHeaderMapper() {

            @Override
            protected void populateUserDefinedHeader(String headerName, Object headerValue, SoapMessage target) {
                super.populateUserDefinedHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml", target);
            }

            @Override
            protected void populateStandardHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers, SoapMessage target) {
                headers.put(WebServiceHeaders.SOAP_ACTION,
                        "http://www.example.com/SOAUI/ServiceHeader/V4");
                super.populateStandardHeaders(headers, target);
            }

            @Override
            public void fromHeadersToRequest(MessageHeaders headers, SoapMessage target) {
                SaajSoapMessage targetMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) target;
                SoapHeader header = targetMessage.getEnvelope().getHeader();
                //Constructing SOAP Header

                JAXBElement<ObjectType34> trackingHdrTypeJAXBElement = ObjectFactory().createHdr(ObjectType34);
                jaxb2Marshaller().marshal(trackingHdrTypeJAXBElement, header.getResult());
                System.out.println(header.getResult());
            }

            @Override
            public void setRequestHeaderNames(String... requestHeaderNames) {
                super.setRequestHeaderNames("*");
            }
        });
        gateway.setMessageFactory(new SaajSoapMessageFactory() {

            @Override
            public void setSoapVersion(SoapVersion version) {
                super.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_11);
            }
        });
        return gateway;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to share some debug logs to confirm that your custom `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` isn't called? How about to place a break point in the `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` and debug the application to figure out what's going on? According to your code there is nothing to hook the problem.

Comment: What does it mean? Plus it's not readable from the comment. Just take a look to it by yourself! You always can edit your question with more info and proper formatting

Comment: Hey Artem, pressed enter too fast : , here is the inspect on the doHandle in `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`

`payload = {JAXBElement@5161} 
 headers = {MessageHeaders@5162}  size = 4
  0 = "replyChannel" -> 
  1 = "errorChannel" -> 
  2 = "id" -> "ce84a3c4-e29d-bded-3cdf-e8cd6f90b5a6"
  3 = "timestamp" -> "1504575027474"`

Custom headers are not part of the Message

Comment: Doesn't debug in the IDE help to go from line to line to see the problem?

Comment: May be i couldn't articulate the issue in the first post itself.  gateway.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultSoapHeaderMapper() { })  , none of the overridden methods are . getting called

Comment: I don't see big problems in your code. Only the concern bothers me is about your overridden setters: if no body calls them , they don't delegate. I'll try to come up with some simple sample for you in the morning, but any way would be great if you could jump from line to line via debug tool. Spring is open source anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Modified the code

```
@Bean
    public DefaultSoapHeaderMapper headerMapper11() {

        return new DefaultSoapHeaderMapper() {
            @Override
            public void fromHeadersToRequest(MessageHeaders headers, SoapMessage target) {
                SaajSoapMessage targetMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) target;
                SoapHeader header = targetMessage.getEnvelope().getHeader();
                //Constructing SOAP Header
                JAXBElement<ObjectType34> trackingHdrTypeJAXBElement = ObjectFactory().createHdr(ObjectType34);
                jaxb2Marshaller().marshal(trackingHdrTypeJAXBElement, header.getResult());
                super.fromHeadersToRequest(headers, target);
            }
        };

    }
```

and set the header using the method call:

```
gateway.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper11());
```

Now the overridden method is getting called and having the header as well.

Code is working as expected now.

Comment: Glad to see you've figured out that! +1